# IF value of Sheet1 B2 matches value in array Sheet2 B2:B37 insert value of Sheet2 C2:C37

Tags: arrays, excel, if-statement, match

What I am trying to accomplish with this formula is to match values in Sheet1 B2:B132 with the same value in Sheet2 B2:B37. If they match to then copy the value in Sheet2 C2:C37 into Sheet1 C2:C132. I know this sounds confusing. Hopefully these images will make more sense.

Sheet1:
[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

The data is not proprietary so I can share the .xlsx if it is allowed (not sure so, I didn't). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards, 
Mike Chace

Comment: I'm guessing you can use XLOOKUP or VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH on the Product Build number?

Comment: Use a combination of `=INDEX(MATCH`

Comment: Probably something like this: `=INDEX(Builds!C:C,MATCH('Asset - Office products'!B2,Builds!B:B,0))`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly,
How about? **=IF(COUNTIF( Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$4, Sheet2!A2)> 0, Sheet1!B2, "")**

Sheet1!$A$1:Sheet1!$A$4 - The range you looking in 
Sheet2!A2 - The value you want to find in the range
Sheet1!B2 - The value you paste if the condition is correct

The formula should be pasted to the cell you want the result to be in